# Recyclerview view not displaying list item correctly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-recyclerview

[Screenshot of the recyclerview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dnn7h.jpg)
I want the image view width to be match parent, but I am not able to understand what is wrong?
I have set that base element to match parent and then add constraint to be match parent, but on running the code the list items are not constrained to the parent.Any help would be helpful.

RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".favourites.FavouritesFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/fav_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#C1D1E1"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:listitem="@layout/memes_list_item" />

</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

List item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

 <data>

    <variable
        name="memes"
        type="com.example.mememvvm.database.MemesEntity" />
</data>


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/meme_image_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            app:imageUrl="@{memes.url}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

            tools:src="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>


    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_like_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/acme"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="@{Integer.toString(memes.ups)}"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/ic_thumb_up"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/card_view"
        tools:text="999" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

Adapter:

```
class FavouritesAdapter() :
ListAdapter<MemesEntity, FavouritesAdapter.FavouritesViewHolder>(DiffCallBack) {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): FavouritesViewHolder {
    return 
FavouritesViewHolder(MemesListItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)))
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FavouritesViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val memes = getItem(position)
    holder.bind(memes)
}

companion object DiffCallBack : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<MemesEntity>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: MemesEntity, newItem: MemesEntity): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: MemesEntity, newItem: MemesEntity): Boolean {
        return oldItem.url == newItem.url
    }

}

class FavouritesViewHolder(private var binding: MemesListItemBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun bind(memes: MemesEntity) {
        //binding.recyclerViewLikeTextView.text = memes.ups.toString()
        //Glide.with()
        binding.memes = memes
        binding.executePendingBindings()
    }
}
```

}

Calling function Code:
class FavouritesFragment : Fragment() {

```
private lateinit var binding: FragmentFavouritesBinding
private lateinit var viewModel: FavouritesViewModel

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    binding = FragmentFavouritesBinding.inflate(inflater)

    val application = requireNotNull(this.activity).application
    val datasource = MemesDatabase.getInstance(application).memesDao
    val viewModelFactory = FavouritesViewModelFactory(datasource)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(FavouritesViewModel::class.java)


    val adapter = FavouritesAdapter()
    binding.favRecyclerView.adapter = adapter



    viewModel.memesList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { memesList ->
        memesList.let {
            adapter.submitList(memesList)
        }
    })

    binding.lifecycleOwner = this



    return binding.root
 }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are inflating a view in onCreateViewHolder, you have to specify ViewGroup as parent.

**Try changing**

`FavouritesViewHolder(MemesListItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)))`

**To**

`FavouritesViewHolder(MemesListItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false))`